# How do you insert HTML into a text node in AngleSharp?

Tags: anglesharp

I'm parsing a document with AngleSharp.  I have a text node (NodeName: "#text") and I want to insert some HTML in it.  I can certainly reset NodeValue to whatever I want, but it's still a text node, so all the brackets are escaped.

How do I take the string value of a text node, inject some HTML into it, then have a parsed DOM representation that that HTML take the place of the original text node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you want is to replace a single text node by multiple nodes.

For instance `<div>foo</div>`, i.e.,

```
+ root
  + textnode
```

becomes

```
+ root
  + textnode (1)
  + element
  + textnode (2)
```

which could `<div>f<b>o</b>o</div>`. The simplest way I can think of is just replacing the node.

```
var source = @"<div>foo</div>";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(source);
var div = document.QuerySelector("div");
div.InnerHtml = div.InnerHtml.Replace("foo", "f<b>o</b>o");
```

Now you can argue that just replacing the text may not be what you want. You maybe have already elements that you want to insert. Therefore a better (yet more complex) way would be to split the text node and insert the remaining contents.

```
var source = @"<div>foo</div>";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(source);
var div = document.QuerySelector("div");
var text = div.TextContent;
div.RemoveChild(div.FirstChild); // assuming there is only one child
var bold = document.CreateElement("b");
bold.TextContent = text.Substring(1, 1); //o
div.Append(
    document.CreateTextNode(text.Substring(0, 1)), //f
    bold,
    document.CreateTextNode(text.Substring(2, 1)));//o
```

Depending in your use-case there may be a more simple solution.

Comment: My problem: I was trying to do the replacement on TextContent.

Comment: Yes, but the TextContent is just plain text (a `string`). Therefore you have to go to the containing node (which is a `TextNode`) and do modifications on it.Maybe I can insert some helpers to do it more efficiently (using extension methods - just like the other helpers).

Comment: Is this a true statement: when you set the `InnerHtml` property of a node, it re-parses and resets its child nodes?  My testing seems to indicate that's true.

Comment: It is true. `InnerHtml` will throw away all connected nodes and re-evaluate the given string using the HTML parser (in fragment node; using itself as a the fragment context). It is thus a very expensive operation (same is true in every browser).

Comment: Well, then there's my solution (except for the unfortunate "very expensive" detail...).  This is basically what I wanted to do.